# I need help inserting a link into my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my SQL query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `diploma`(`id`, `diploma_name`, `diploma_type`, `diploma_info`,        `diploma_pdf`, `diploma_theme`, `diploma_link`) "
        . "VALUES (0,'Diploma in Programming','This is the diploma info','/image/diploma.pdf','i','<a href='http://dmsd8.trytocode.com/subProgrammePage.php?type_id=$diploma_type'>Click here for more information</a>')";
```

But when I echo out the query, it is a clickable link instead of the codes is that any way to insert into the database the codes only?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to insert or you want to print? Very confusing question.

Comment: What do you mean by "codes"?

Comment: You say when you echo it, it is a clickable link? Obviously that means that it did indeed write the code to the database. When you echo it, it is rendered as html instead of a text string.

Comment: I wish to insert the a href link into the database so that when I retrieve it from the database I can click on the link, when I echo the query out the last value of the query is an a href link

Comment: Errors if any? Checking for them? If you're not checking for them, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a clickable link because you are outputting the text into an HTML document.

If you don't want it to be treated as raw HTML, then [encode it with `htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

(But do that when inserting into the HTML document, not the database. Do all encoding Just In Time).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the hyperlink's href has single quote which make the query invalid.

Replace href's `'` (single quote) with `"` (double quote) will fix the issue.

```
<a href="...">Click here for more information</a>
        ^   ^
        |   |
```

In addition, one value is missing in the query (might be **diploma_type**) -

```
INSERT  INTO diploma
        ( id ,
          diploma_name ,
          diploma_type ,
          diploma_info ,
          diploma_pdf ,
          diploma_theme ,
          diploma_link
        )
VALUES  ( 0 ,
          'Diploma in Programming' ,
          'MISSING_DIPLOMA_TYPE' ,
          'This is the diploma info' ,
          '/image/diploma.pdf' ,
          'i' ,
          '<a href="...">Click here for more information</a>'
        )
```

Comment: That would make the query invalid, but the question does not describe the problem as the query failing to run. Presumably the code in the question does not accurately reflect the way the data is being put in the database.